# My python wolf-goat-cabbage script crashes python 2.6

Tags: python, crash, python-2.6, depth-first-search

i am trying to create a script that solves the wolf cabbage goat. whenever i run my code python crashes. what is wrong with my code that makes it not work? i am trying to get it so that the code runs and then print out each step in the solving of the problem.

search.py

```
class Nodes:
    def succ(self, n):
        raise Exception, "Successor undefined"
    def start(self):
        raise Exception, "Start undefined"
    def goal(self, n):
        raise Exception, "Goal undefined"
```

wolf_cabbage_goat.py

```
import search # get the interface

def other_side(left_right):
    if left_right == 'left': return 'right'
    elif left_right == 'right': return 'left'

def safe(node):
    # the side without the farmer needs check,
    # the other is safe
    side_without_farmer = other_side(node['farmer'])

    lone_travelers = set(traveler for traveler in node if node[traveler] == side_without_farmer)

    # dangeroos animals
    unsafe = set(['wolf', 'goat']).issubset(lone_travelers) or\
             set(['goat', 'cabbage']).issubset(lone_travelers)
    return not unsafe

class Wolf_Cabbage_Goat(search.Nodes):
    def start(self):
        # farmer, wolf, cabbage, goat on one side
        return { 'farmer': 'left',
                 'wolf': 'left',
                 'goat': 'left',
                 'cabbage': 'left' }

    def goal(self, node):
        # true if all moved to right
        return set(node[i] for i in node) == set(['right'])

    def succ(self, node):
        for traveler in node.keys() + ['']:
            # for all possible travelers, including none

            if traveler == 'farmer':
                continue
            # ignore, we'll deal separately with him

            new_node = node.copy()
            # create a safety copy

            # if somebody wants to travel, and the farmer is on the
            # same side, do it

            if traveler and new_node[traveler] == new_node['farmer']:
                new_node[traveler] = other_side(new_node[traveler])

            # the farmer always travels
            new_node['farmer'] = other_side(new_node['farmer'])

            # after a trip, the new state is ok if no one gets eaten
            if safe(new_node):
                yield new_node
```

depth_first_search.py

```
def depth_first_search(problem, node):
    if problem.goal(node): return [node]
    # base case
    for n_succ in problem.succ(node):
        sol = depth_first_search(problem, n_succ)
        if sol:
            # first path is returned
            return [node] + sol
```

wcg_run.py

```
import wolf_cabbage_goat
from depth_first_search import *

wcg = wolf_cabbage_goat.Wolf_Cabbage_Goat()
print depth_first_search(wcg, wcg.start())
```

Comment: Show the error message please.

Comment: @laike9m no error code pops up. theres just a window that says "pythonw.exe has stopped working" and give me the option to close the program

Comment: Did it work on other versions of python? Why do you use 2.6?

Comment: @Vincent Beltman As part of our course we are using 2.6 for our assignments. and therefor would be better if i learnt in 2.6

Answer (score 0):

If the error is unresolved reference, I think it is because of these:

```
one_travelers = set(traveler for traveler in node if node[traveler] == side_without_farmer)

# dangeroos animals
unsafe = set(['wolf', 'goat']).issubset(lone_travelers)
```

You declared one_travelers and used lone_travelers.

It is a good practice to post error with such a question. Also you can avoid such errors if you use a good ide like pycharm (I like pycharm)

Comment: sorry that was a typo on my part. code has been edited

Comment: Actually it is crashing for me with error: maximum recursion depth reached. I tried running it from pyCharm. I guess same thing is happening for you. You can try changing the limit by modifying sys.setrecursionlimit to a higher value